# Set bounds for draggable element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I have a draggable element that is dynamically generated by jQuery. I have a background image within the div. How can I bind the element so it never goes outside the div?

Here's the code: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/axtruo/vjh5K/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#currentimage").append('<img id="dragable" src="http://s25.postimg.org/pi8ruls3z/image.jpg" width="200px" height="auto" />');
        $("#dragable").draggable();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `containment: 'parent'`. Also you have to add class `dragable` not id. Id must be unique. So that you can click the button more than one time.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#currentimage").append('<img class="dragable" src="http://s25.postimg.org/pi8ruls3z/image.jpg" width="200px" height="auto" />');
        $(".dragable").draggable({
        containment: 'parent' 
        });         
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vjh5K/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use containment to restrict it container

```
containment: $('#currentimage')
```

**FYI**

ID must be unique

```
.append('<img id="dragable"
```

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178)

you are adding images with same id.

---

You can use class

```
.append('<img class="dragable"
```

Than use

```
$(".dragable").draggable();
```

---

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AYA6g/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var el = '<img src="http://s25.postimg.org/pi8ruls3z/image.jpg" width="200px" height="auto" />';
        $("#currentimage").append($(el).draggable({ containment: $("#currentimage") }));
    });
});
```